# What is the correct way to call the pure virtual member when another member exists with another signature?

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

I have a pure virtual interface class and a derived class that look like this

```
class IInterface
{
public:
    virtual void func() = 0;
};

class MyClass : public IInterface
{
public:
    void func(int i) { func(); }
};
```

The compiler complains that the call to `func()` in `func(int i)` does not take 0 arguments. What is the correct way to specify calling the pure virtual member?

The 2 solutions I came up with were

```
void func(int i) { static_cast<IInterface*>(this)->func(); }
```

and

```
void func(int i) { IInterface::func(); }
```

Are either of these viable? Is there a better way? Both seem clunky.

Comment: Your second solution is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Why would you want to actually call a pure virtual method?

Comment: `void dontHideBaseMembers(int i) { func(); }`

Comment: In your edit you aren't including a body for `func()` in `MyClass` so it wouldn't build anyway. Once you do, does it still not work? If `func` is defined with a no-arguments overload in `MyClass` it should compile and solve your issue.

Comment: You just forgot to implement `func()` in `MyClass`.

Comment: @VoidStar if OP define func() in MyClass he can call it directly, no need of any circus

Comment: @FailedDev Because MyClass is a helper parent class implementing parts of IInterface but not all. This was a trivial example of my problem

Comment: @cppguy But there's no problem in this case, so it's not an example of your problem, whatever it is.

Comment: @JonathanPotter That turns off virtual dispatch.

Comment: It's an incorrect situation. There is no implementation for `void func() = 0` so you don't want to call it anyway. If there was, in this case it would be present in `MyClass` and the problem wouldn't arise, as the overload wouldn't hide the original in the base class. In general your second technique is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Okay, so MyClass is deliberately abstract still. That's an edge case for the language, you'll need `IInterface::func();`.

Comment: @VoidStar This class is a simplification of a problem where MyClass is a partial implementation of IInterface that happens to have another function with the same name

Comment: @EJP: No, this can still work as long as he doesn't try to instance `MyClass`. That is, `MyClass` is abstract. He can subclass `MyClass` and provide the full definitions there.

Comment: Sometimes you can't win on SO - half the time you get beaten up for not providing a MCVE, and the other half because your example was too minimal :)

Comment: @cppguy your first example seems to be right for your issue

Comment: @JonathanPotter yeah, it can get ugly fast here

Comment: Probably this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @DeanSeo I tried to provide a minimal example. If you can't answer the question, don't. Leaving a derived class as still partially abstract is perfectly common. Would you rather I'd posted 500 lines of noise?

Comment: The question title is misleading, your problem is independent from using *pure virtual* functions, *virtual* would be enough. And the signature isn't just different, but the name is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bring the base class declaration into derived class scope with a *using-declaration*:

```
class MyClass : public IInterface
{
public:
    using IInterface::func;
    void func(int i) { func(); }
};
```

Alternatively, convert `this` to a pointer to base will also work (i.e., your first option):

```
void func(int i) { static_cast<IInterface*>(this)->func(); }
```

`IInterface::func();` won't work, as explicit qualification disables virtual dispatch.

Comment: It's ugly but it'll have to do. I find it strange that the language requires this but there's no ambiguity when the functions are in the same class

Comment: @cppguy in C++ names declared in a scope hide the same name that was in a previous scope; it's similar to `int x = 4; { int x; x = 5; } cout << x;` getting you `4`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid hiding a name from a base class, you can employ a `using` statement:

```
class MyClass : public IInterface
{
public:
    using IInterface::func;      // prevents `func()` from being hidden by `func(int)`

    void func(int i) { func(); }
};
```

This is described in Item 33: "Avoid hiding inherited names" of Scott Meyers' "Effective C++, Third Edition".

Answer (score 1):

The code `void func(int i) { func(); }` does not work because when you declare `func` in the scope of `MyClass`, that name hides any other names called `func` that are in base classes.

If you want `IInterface`'s `func()` to be generally usable in the scope `MyClass` the simplest solution is:

```
using IInterface::func;
```

which can go in MyClass's class definition (and will respect the access specifier that you put it under); or you can only put it inside `func(int i)`. After doing this, calls to `func` from the scope of `MyClass` will do overload resolution between `func()` and `func(int)`.

---

`static_cast<IInterface*>(this)->func();` will also work: it will invoke final overrider of `func()` for the object you're currently working with.

The version `IInterface::func()` does not do virtual dispatch; it actually calls the specific function `IInterface::func`. If you didn't define such a function then you will cause undefined behaviour; which will perhaps show up as a linker error, or a runtime error about an attempt to call a pure virtual function.

NB. In case you are unaware, pure virtual functions may also have a body defined but this is rarely done outside of destructors.